# Trying to mock Stenciljs store (@stencil/store) state (multiple times) while writing unit test for Web Components

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, web-component, stenciljs

I am working on writing Unit Tests for Web Components. These Web Components are built using [Stenciljs](https://stenciljs.com/). StencilJS uses Jest for defining and running these unit tests. Also, I am new to Jest and StencilJS, so my methods may not be as per some defined standards. Let me describe the application and my problem.

The project has a global state defined in a file using [Stencil-Store](https://stenciljs.com/docs/stencil-store). The content of the file looks like this:

`global/store.ts`

```
    import { createStore } from '@stencil/store';

      const { state } = createStore({
        appName: 'Application Name',
        platformName: 'Platform Name',
        mode: 'default', // light, dark, default
        appActionBar: 'closed', // open, closed 
      });

    export default state;
```

So in any component where we need information from the state or if the component needs to update information in the state, we import this `state` in that component and perform any action. For example, consider a Web Component `app-shell`

`app.shell.tsx`

```
    import { Component, h, Host } from '@stencil/core';
    import state from './global/store';

    @Component({
      tag: 'app-shell',
      styleUrl: 'app-shell.scss',
      shadow: true,
    })
    export class AppShell {
    render() {
        return (
          <Host
            data-mode={state.mode}
            class={{
              'action-bar-closed': state.appActionBar === 'closed',
              'action-bar-open': state.appActionBar === 'open',
            }}
          >
            {/* Header */}
            <div
              class={{
                'app-shell-header': true,
                'side-panel-open': state.sidepanel === true,
              }}
            >
              <slot name="app-shell-header"></slot>
            </div>
            {/* Shell Content */}
            <div class="app-shell-content">
              <slot name="app-shell-content"></slot>
            </div>
          </Host>
    }
    }
```

As you can notice in above code that this web component reads values from the `state` and applies `classes` based on that. Now in order to test different classes getting applied, I thought it would a great idea to `mock the state` and provide different values of `states` for different tests.

So with this in mind, I started writing test for this web component. I referred to [mocking](https://stenciljs.com/docs/mocking) doc from StencilJS and testing doc in general. Here is a `spec` file:

`app-shell.spec.ts`

```
    // Mock the global state for testing purposes.
    jest.mock('./global/store', () => {
      const { state } = createStore({
        appName: 'Mocked Name',
        platformName: 'Mocked Platform Name',
        mode: 'default',
        appActionBar: 'closed',
      });
      return state;
    });
    import { newSpecPage, SpecPage } from '@stencil/core/testing';
    import { createStore } from '@stencil/store';
    import { AppShell } from './app-shell';

    describe('app-shell', () => {
      let page: SpecPage;
      let element: any;
      let componentInstance: any;

      beforeEach(async () => {
        page = await newSpecPage({
          components: [AppShell],
          html: `<app-shell></app-shell>`,
          supportsShadowDom: true,
        });
        element = page.doc.querySelector('app-shell');
        componentInstance = page.rootInstance;
      });
      describe('build and render', () => {
        it('should build', async () => {
          expect(page).toBeTruthy();
        });
        it('should render', async () => {
          expect(page.root).toEqualHtml(`
          <app-shell class="action-bar-closed" data-mode="default">
            <mock:shadow-root>
              <div class="app-shell-header">
                <slot name="app-shell-header"></slot>
              </div>
              <div class="app-shell-content">
                <slot name="app-shell-content"></slot>
              </div>
            </mock:shadow-root>
          </app-shell>
        `);
        });
      });
    })

;
```

So by following the StencilJS mocking documentation, I was able to mock the state value (as seen in above spec file) using `jest.mock()`. So when I run this test, I get the mocked state values as defined in this spec file. All good!

**Problem**

However, I wanted to **override/update** the mocked state values for different `describe` under the same `spec` file so that I can provide `different` state values to test separate cases.

So for example, I want to achieve something like this.

```
// Mock the global state for testing purposes.
    jest.mock('./global/store', () => {
      const { state } = createStore({
        appName: 'Mocked Name',
        platformName: 'Mocked Platform Name',
        mode: 'default',
        appActionBar: 'closed',
      });
      return state;
    });
    import { newSpecPage, SpecPage } from '@stencil/core/testing';
    import { createStore } from '@stencil/store';
    import { AppShell } from './app-shell';

    describe('app-shell', () => {
      let page: SpecPage;
      let element: any;
      let componentInstance: any;

      beforeEach(async () => {
        page = await newSpecPage({
          components: [AppShell],
          html: `<app-shell></app-shell>`,
          supportsShadowDom: true,
        });
        element = page.doc.querySelector('app-shell');
        componentInstance = page.rootInstance;
      });
      describe('build and render', () => {
        it('should build', async () => {
          expect(page).toBeTruthy();
        });
        it('should render', async () => {
          expect(page.root).toEqualHtml(`
          <app-shell class="action-bar-closed" data-mode="default">
            <mock:shadow-root>
              <div class="app-shell-header">
                <slot name="app-shell-header"></slot>
              </div>
              <div class="app-shell-content">
                <slot name="app-shell-content"></slot>
              </div>
            </mock:shadow-root>
          </app-shell>
        `);
        });
      });
      describe('mock state again', () => {
        it('should have new mocked values', async () => {
           // Mock the global state for testing purposes.
           jest.mock('./global/store', () => {
           const { state } = createStore({
             appName: 'Mocked Name',
             platformName: 'Mocked Platform Name',
             mode: 'dark',
             appActionBar: 'open',
         });
      return state;
    });
          // Have expect statement here... 
        });
      });
    })
;
```

As you would notice in the above code snippet, I am trying to `mock` the `state` twice using `jest.mock()`. However, I am not able to mock the state again.

**Question**
What is the correct way to solve my issue i.e. able to mock state multiple times in a single spec file?

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer this question here.

So I got my answer on StencilJS Slack group within minutes after posting this question link.

Thank you @simon-hänisch

First of all you **do not need to mock the store at all** and can update the state itself directly from the `Spec` file.

I had to make of couple of changes:

1) So I changed my `store.ts`  to export `dispose()`  along with state.

```
export const { state, dispose } = createStore({ ... })
```

2) Next, I updated my `spec`  file to something like below:

```
import {state, dispose} from '../global/store';

  beforeEach(async () => {
    dispose();
    page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [AppShell],
      html: `<app-shell></app-shell>`,
      supportsShadowDom: true,
    });
    element = page.doc.querySelector('app-shell');
    componentInstance = page.rootInstance;
  });

describe('my test', () => {
  it('light mode', async () => {
    // update state
    state.mode = 'light';
    // expect statement
    ...
  });
  it('dark mode', async () => {
    // update state
    store.mode = 'dark';
    // expect statement
    ...
  });
});
```

I do all the setup in `beforeEach` now, the only thing I need to do is call `dispose` before I create `page`.

By updating the state this way, I do not need to mock the state.

Hopefully, this will be useful to many newbies (like me) to StencilJS :)